# What causes the "Page Header plus Page Footer is too large for the page" error in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have used the following code for a print button:

```
Data.str = null;
//Data.str = textBox24.Text.ToString();
string s = "select * from temp_bond";
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Real.mdb";
cn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(s, cn);
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds);
Bond rpt = new Bond();
rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "BOND_" + Data.str + ".pdf");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("BOND_" + Data.str + ".pdf");
//r.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "E:\\rep.pdf");
//crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
OleDbCommand cm1 = new OleDbCommand("delete * from temp_bond", cn);
cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

and I'm getting an error in this code:

```
rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "BOND_" + Data.str + ".pdf");
```

The error is:

> Page Header plus Page Footer is too large for the page. Error in File
>   C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\temp_3f674868-8e5d-46ce-80eb-dce78bb2ba89
>   {17674136-B71E-4C6F-9E36-1CEB514B13BF}.rpt: Page header or footer
>   longer than a page.

What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error seems quite self-explanatory - if you add the height of the header to the height of the footer, it's taller than a page, and therefore can't be rendered. You need to redesign your report in the Crystal Reports designer.

Comment: Simon, there could be more to this issue than the error message implies.  I'm marking this to be reopened.  This possibly/probably due to a printer driver issue.  CR is exceptionally finicky and, generally, the worst piece of software ever written.  Please don't be so quick to judge and write off a question without asking for further information.

Comment: I'll convert this to an answer if this q is reopened. CR doesn't like it when your default printer has a page-size setting that isn't equal or greater to the page layout of the report. In my case, a user was having trouble b/c he installed a label printer and the installer made itself the default printer.  Since the labels were much smaller than the 8.5x11" paper, CR was crashing when it would attempt to create the report. In my case, I always create a PDF. That didn't matter.  If there is an issue with the default printer page size, it will crash the CR engine.

Answer (score 23):

I have an application that has been published for years and uses Crystal Reports as an embedded document generation tool.  The report that is included with my application has been working for years, and I was stumped for a while when I received a support call from a user who had received this exact error message.

After a bit of head-scratching and research, I've found that the primary culprit is the default printer on the end-users computer.  ***If the default printer is currently configured to print on paper of a different size that is smaller than the report you are generating, Crystal Reports will give you this error message.***  Also, you will receive this message if the printer is set to print in an orientation different than the orientation of your CR report.

The really odd/poorly designed issue with this bug is that you will receive it, even if you declare to the runtime to simply create a PDF.  I assume CR is using some of the default printer settings to initialize the runtime.

You have a few options to fix this.  First, you can change the default printer to another device.  You may have to do this if your default printer is of a different, non-typical form factor (e.g. a label printer.)  Crystal Reports will not like the label printer if the labels are smaller than your document.

Option two is, of course, to reconfigure your printer driver to specify a paper type that is large enough to fit your document.  Also, as mentioned, be sure that the paper printing preference is also set to print in the correct orientation (landscape or portrait) as your Crystal Report document expects.

Last, you can change your default printer to another printer or remove the printer from your PC.  This isn't the most favorable answer, but it may be a last-case necessary step to get the message to go away.

Comment: That and use the `report.Export(exportOptions);` method.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar problem, but I couldn't resolve it by changing the default printer or by changing the settings of them.

I managed to solve the problem by setting the parameters of the report by code, manually.

This is an example to show you.

```
dim crep As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
crep.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait
crep.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4
```

Saludos a todos! =)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I changed the default printer to Microsoft XPS Writer.  This corrected my the display of the crystal reports.

Answer (score 1):

Check the header or another object.

Set properties:

```
can grow = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this error with a Crystal Report that has been running in my MS Dynamics environment for YEARS without problem.  After a bit of head scratching and Googling, one of my users said "oh, I guess you want me to delete all the NOTES on the Order".

My Crystal report template has a "Notes" box in the Header of the report.  In the design, it is fitted to have 1 line of notes, and the form fits an A4 page.

[Quote Form]

The user entered over 40 lines of Notes into that box.... hence it pushed it outside the bounds of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error when printing to a Dot-matrix printer that was deployed in Windows Server 2019.

The users would get this error when trying to print from Terralink Database that uses Crystal Reports to an Epson FX-890.

Error:567 Error in File 
Page header or footer longer than a page.

After reading that suggestion above I was successful in getting rid of the error by 
going back into users' printer settings under advanced document settings and making sure in this case that it was defaulted to 8.5x11 letter page.

Thank you for the help.

-Raj

Comment: I’m glad to hear that you were able to resolve your issue based on the previous answers! In the future, once you’ve earned more reputation on Stack Overflow, you’ll be able to upvote answers as a way of validating their usefulness and thanking their authors. Later yet, you’ll be able to leave comments if you want to expand on a point (e.g., by noting that the fix works for a particular error). In the meanwhile, however, you should avoid leaving answers that validate existing answers, as they give future readers more answers to sort through to find their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing page size of crystal report by Right click on report DESIGN--> PAGE SETUP ... Try it with A4, Landscape and others as per need.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with a Zebra label printer configured by the network on a Windows Server as the print server. I didn't want to try to change settings on the client default printer, because I can't be sure which client will print. Instead, I fixed it in the driver settings (printer defaults) on the print server (Windows Server 2008). So on the print server:

1. Go to "Devices and Printers" and choose the affected printer.
2. Right-click and choose "Printer properties".
3. Go to the "General" tab and click on the button "Change Properties" at the bottom.
4. Go to the "Advanced" tab and click on the button "Printing Defaults...".
5. Go to the "Page Setup" tab and define the settings you want (size, orientation).
6. Click "OK" as many times as you need to save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

After the long search and try,i found that when crystal viewer load the page setup with four margin (top, bottom,left,right) changed automatic. So always write them in your code. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off "Adjust Automatically" in Design -> Page Setup -> Margins.